# Is it normal for a Graphics card to operate in 90 degree temperature?

Tags: temperature, graphics, nvidia-quadro

Is it quite normal that GPU operates under 90+ degrees?

I have two boxes which has nVidia Quadro 580 and 4000.

The first heats up to 60 degrees but Quadro 4000 goes like 70-90 degree. Is this quite normal?

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Is this quite normal?

Apparently it is.  From multiple different posts around the internet, it appears that this is considered a video card that runs hot.  Don't worry, there are a bunch of different video cards that are known to run hot.  Since this is a professional grade card, it apparently is configured to run quiet, as opposed to having the fan run loud and cool better.

You may be able to use [MSI Afterburner](http://event.msi.com/vga/afterburner/download.htm) or [EVGA Precision](http://www.evga.com/precision/) or any other overclocking/underclocking software suite to crank the fan up.  Some have had luck doing it this way.

You may also have to remove the heat sink, and repaste the processor.

You may also shave a couple of degrees by adjusting the position of the heat sink.  One screw having been overtightened can make the heat sink sit improperly on the processor... which can result in temps a little higher than expected.

However.... load temps of 70-80c are expected for this card.